# HTML Table indents unexpectadly

Tags: html, css

Why is my HTML indenting like this?

The following is my table. All the cells should correctly align in the columns. ie. 'First Word' should be on top of each other. For some reason I get an indentation of one cell. I am not sure what this is happening.

```
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr class="tdc1">
        <td>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" width="100%" bgcolor="white">
                <tr class="tableheadersmall">
                    <td width="10%">1</td>
                    <td width="25%">2</td>
                    <td width="12%">3</td>
                    <td width="18%">4</td>
                    <td width="5%">5</td>
                    <td width="30%">6</td>
                </tr>
                <tbody id="linumAppointmentsContainer">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6" style="height: 1px; background-color: #000000;">
                            <!-- black line -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tabbright">
                        <td style="vertical-align: top" rowSpan="53" class="tabbright"> First Word</td>
                        <td>OD</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>offen</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6" style="height: 1px; background-color: #000000;">
                            <!-- black line -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tabbright">
                        <td style="vertical-align: top" rowSpan="20">First Word</td>
                        <td>OD</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>offen</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/U34Cb/

Comment: removing rowspan="53" should do the trick. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U34Cb/4/)

Comment: or leave rowspan="53" and remove one of TD in next rows: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/U34Cb/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Your first "First Word" cell has rowspan="53" which means it takes another 52 rows beneath it, so in the next row, "First Row" starts after the spanned row from the above.

Should you add 52 rows between two "First Word" td, your alignment would return to normal for the next "First Word" cell.

Answer (score 0):

If Im right in thinking what you're after, remove `rowSpan="53"`